# Unity project: screen resolution dynamically changes on android device Xiaomi Mi A3

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

Screen.height and Screen.width changes dynamically after game launching.

**How I reproduced it:**

a. Create a project

b. Take Xiaomi Mi A3 phone

c. Create any object

d. Log Screen.width and Screen.height in console after object's Start event

e. Build and Run game on an android device

f. Connect to device with the adb to see logs

g. Search following output:

1. "InitializeOrResetSwapChain 720x1490"
2. "InitializeOrResetSwapChain 720x1490"

And after there have to be your resolution output, for example

3. "ScreenSize: h = 1490, w = 720"

And then, after +-3 seconds!

4. "InitializeOrResetSwapChain 720x1560"

After this event my UI became ugly, because I have already remembered 720x1490

Log example:

```
2019-12-22 00:09:25.645 12911-12911/? I/oss.BlockPuzzl: Late-enabling -Xcheck:jni
2019-12-22 00:09:25.720 12911-12911/{ProjectPackageName} I/Perf: Connecting to perf service.
2019-12-22 00:09:25.778 12911-12911/{ProjectPackageName} D/Unity: CommandLine:  
2019-12-22 00:09:25.781 12911-12911/{ProjectPackageName} D/OpenGLRenderer: Skia GL Pipeline
2019-12-22 00:09:25.796 12911-12911/{ProjectPackageName} I/Unity: onResume
2019-12-22 00:09:25.835 12911-12928/{ProjectPackageName} D/Unity: SetWindow 0 0xed8c7808
2019-12-22 00:09:25.836 12911-12928/{ProjectPackageName} D/Unity: SetWindow 0 0xed8c7808
2019-12-22 00:09:25.851 12911-12911/{ProjectPackageName} I/Unity: windowFocusChanged: true
2019-12-22 00:09:25.857 12911-12928/{ProjectPackageName} E/SchedPolicy: set_timerslack_ns write failed: Operation not permitted
2019-12-22 00:09:25.861 12911-12928/{ProjectPackageName} D/Unity: Enabling Unity systrace
2019-12-22 00:09:25.864 12911-12928/{ProjectPackageName} W/oss.BlockPuzzl: Accessing hidden method Ljava/lang/invoke/MethodHandles$Lookup;-><init>(Ljava/lang/Class;I)V (light greylist, reflection)
2019-12-22 00:09:25.870 12911-12928/{ProjectPackageName} D/Unity: [VFS] Mount /data/app/{ProjectPackageName}-XKbdUqctrLZM0LP_xUxbMA==/base.apk
2019-12-22 00:09:25.883 12911-12928/{ProjectPackageName} I/Unity: SystemInfo CPU = ARMv7 VFPv3 NEON, Cores = 8, Memory = 3611mb
2019-12-22 00:09:25.884 12911-12928/{ProjectPackageName} I/Unity: SystemInfo ARM big.LITTLE configuration: 4 big (mask: 0xf0), 4 little (mask: 0xf)
2019-12-22 00:09:25.884 12911-12928/{ProjectPackageName} I/Unity: ApplicationInfo {ProjectPackageName} version 0.1 build 34932799-1749-4bb8-9aa7-dfd853d6c5a1
2019-12-22 00:09:25.885 12911-12928/{ProjectPackageName} I/Unity: Built from '2019.2/staging' branch, Version '2019.2.17f1 (8e603399ca02)', Build type 'Development', Scripting Backend 'mono', CPU 'armeabi-v7a', Stripping 'Disabled'
2019-12-22 00:09:25.891 12911-12928/{ProjectPackageName} D/Unity: Mono path[0] = '/data/app/{ProjectPackageName}-XKbdUqctrLZM0LP_xUxbMA==/base.apk/assets/bin/Data/Managed'
2019-12-22 00:09:25.891 12911-12928/{ProjectPackageName} D/Unity: Mono config path = 'assets/bin/Data/Managed/etc'
2019-12-22 00:09:25.892 12911-12928/{ProjectPackageName} D/Unity: PlayerConnection initialized from /data/app/{ProjectPackageName}-XKbdUqctrLZM0LP_xUxbMA==/base.apk/assets/bin/Data (debug = 0)
2019-12-22 00:09:25.892 12911-12928/{ProjectPackageName} D/Unity: PlayerConnection initialized network socket : 0.0.0.0 55404
2019-12-22 00:09:25.892 12911-12928/{ProjectPackageName} D/Unity: PlayerConnection initialized unix socket : Unity-{ProjectPackageName}
2019-12-22 00:09:25.893 12911-12928/{ProjectPackageName} D/Unity: Multi-casting "[IP] 192.168.0.101 [Port] 55404 [Flags] 3 [Guid] 4116056835 [EditorId] 3767735054 [Version] 1048832 [Id] AndroidPlayer(Xiaomi_Mi_A3@192.168.0.101) [Debug] 0 [PackageName] AndroidPlayer" to [225.0.0.222:54997]...
2019-12-22 00:09:25.893 12911-12928/{ProjectPackageName} D/Unity: Waiting for connection from host on [0.0.0.0:55404]...
2019-12-22 00:09:26.901 12911-12928/{ProjectPackageName} D/Unity: Remaining time:8s
2019-12-22 00:09:27.910 12911-12928/{ProjectPackageName} D/Unity: Remaining time:7s
2019-12-22 00:09:28.935 12911-12928/{ProjectPackageName} D/Unity: Remaining time:6s
2019-12-22 00:09:29.950 12911-12928/{ProjectPackageName} D/Unity: Remaining time:5s
2019-12-22 00:09:30.985 12911-12928/{ProjectPackageName} D/Unity: Remaining time:4s
2019-12-22 00:09:32.007 12911-12928/{ProjectPackageName} D/Unity: Remaining time:3s
2019-12-22 00:09:33.045 12911-12928/{ProjectPackageName} D/Unity: Remaining time:2s
2019-12-22 00:09:33.722 12911-12926/{ProjectPackageName} I/oss.BlockPuzzl: ProcessProfilingInfo new_methods=90 is saved saved_to_disk=1 resolve_classes_delay=8000
2019-12-22 00:09:34.074 12911-12928/{ProjectPackageName} D/Unity: Remaining time:1s
2019-12-22 00:09:35.114 12911-12928/{ProjectPackageName} D/Unity: Remaining time:0s
2019-12-22 00:09:35.936 12911-12928/{ProjectPackageName} D/Unity: Timed out. Continuing without host connection.
2019-12-22 00:09:35.936 12911-12928/{ProjectPackageName} D/Unity: Started listening to [0.0.0.0:55404]
2019-12-22 00:09:36.029 12911-12928/{ProjectPackageName} D/Unity: [EGL] Attaching window :0xed8c7808
2019-12-22 00:09:36.029 12911-12928/{ProjectPackageName} D/Unity: InitializeScriptEngine OK (0xe518ff00)
2019-12-22 00:09:36.029 12911-12928/{ProjectPackageName} D/Unity: PlayerConnection already initialized - listening to [0.0.0.0:55404]
2019-12-22 00:09:36.033 12911-12928/{ProjectPackageName} E/SchedPolicy: set_timerslack_ns write failed: Operation not permitted
2019-12-22 00:09:36.045 12911-12928/{ProjectPackageName} D/Unity: PlayerInitEngineNoGraphics OK
2019-12-22 00:09:36.045 12911-12928/{ProjectPackageName} D/Unity: AndroidGraphics::Startup window =  0xed8c7808
2019-12-22 00:09:36.045 12911-12928/{ProjectPackageName} D/Unity: [EGL] Attaching window :0xed8c7808
2019-12-22 00:09:36.048 12911-12928/{ProjectPackageName} D/Unity: [XR] Discovering subsystems at path assets/bin/Data/UnitySubsystems
2019-12-22 00:09:36.049 12911-12928/{ProjectPackageName} E/vulkan: invalid vkGetInstanceProcAddr(VK_NULL_HANDLE, "vkDestroyInstance") call
2019-12-22 00:09:36.049 12911-12928/{ProjectPackageName} E/vulkan: invalid vkGetInstanceProcAddr(VK_NULL_HANDLE, "vkEnumeratePhysicalDevices") call
2019-12-22 00:09:36.049 12911-12928/{ProjectPackageName} E/vulkan: invalid vkGetInstanceProcAddr(VK_NULL_HANDLE, "vkGetPhysicalDeviceProperties") call
2019-12-22 00:09:36.051 12911-12928/{ProjectPackageName} D/vulkan: searching for layers in '/data/app/{ProjectPackageName}-XKbdUqctrLZM0LP_xUxbMA==/lib/arm'
2019-12-22 00:09:36.052 12911-12928/{ProjectPackageName} D/vulkan: searching for layers in '/data/app/{ProjectPackageName}-XKbdUqctrLZM0LP_xUxbMA==/base.apk!/lib/armeabi-v7a'
2019-12-22 00:09:36.052 12911-12928/{ProjectPackageName} D/Unity: [Vulkan init] extensions: count=10
2019-12-22 00:09:36.052 12911-12928/{ProjectPackageName} D/Unity: [Vulkan init] extensions: name=VK_KHR_surface, enabled=1
2019-12-22 00:09:36.052 12911-12928/{ProjectPackageName} D/Unity: [Vulkan init] extensions: name=VK_KHR_android_surface, enabled=1
2019-12-22 00:09:36.052 12911-12928/{ProjectPackageName} D/Unity: [Vulkan init] extensions: name=VK_EXT_swapchain_colorspace, enabled=1
2019-12-22 00:09:36.052 12911-12928/{ProjectPackageName} D/Unity: [Vulkan init] extensions: name=VK_KHR_get_surface_capabilities2, enabled=0
2019-12-22 00:09:36.052 12911-12928/{ProjectPackageName} D/Unity: [Vulkan init] extensions: name=VK_EXT_debug_report, enabled=1
2019-12-22 00:09:36.052 12911-12928/{ProjectPackageName} D/Unity: [Vulkan init] extensions: name=VK_KHR_device_group_creation, enabled=0
2019-12-22 00:09:36.052 12911-12928/{ProjectPackageName} D/Unity: [Vulkan init] extensions: name=VK_KHR_external_fence_capabilities, enabled=0
2019-12-22 00:09:36.052 12911-12928/{ProjectPackageName} D/Unity: [Vulkan init] extensions: name=VK_KHR_external_memory_capabilities, enabled=0
2019-12-22 00:09:36.052 12911-12928/{ProjectPackageName} D/Unity: [Vulkan init] extensions: name=VK_KHR_get_physical_device_properties2, enabled=0
2019-12-22 00:09:36.052 12911-12928/{ProjectPackageName} D/Unity: [Vulkan init] extensions: name=VK_KHR_external_semaphore_capabilities, enabled=0
2019-12-22 00:09:36.054 12911-12928/{ProjectPackageName} I/Adreno: QUALCOMM build          : 6cbc6c9, Ib736691963
    Build Date              : 04/25/19
    Shader Compiler Version : EV031.26.03.01
    Local Branch            : 
    Remote Branch           : quic/gfx-adreno.lnx.1.0.r81-rel
    Remote Branch           : NONE
    Reconstruct Branch      : NOTHING
2019-12-22 00:09:36.054 12911-12928/{ProjectPackageName} I/Adreno: Build Config            : S P 6.0.9 AArch32
2019-12-22 00:09:36.055 12911-12928/{ProjectPackageName} D/Unity: Vulkan detection: 2
2019-12-22 00:09:36.055 12911-12928/{ProjectPackageName} D/Unity: GfxDevice: creating device client; threaded=1
2019-12-22 00:09:36.055 12911-12928/{ProjectPackageName} D/Unity: [Vulkan init] extensions: count=10
2019-12-22 00:09:36.055 12911-12928/{ProjectPackageName} D/Unity: [Vulkan init] extensions: name=VK_KHR_surface, enabled=1
2019-12-22 00:09:36.055 12911-12928/{ProjectPackageName} D/Unity: [Vulkan init] extensions: name=VK_KHR_android_surface, enabled=1
2019-12-22 00:09:36.055 12911-12928/{ProjectPackageName} D/Unity: [Vulkan init] extensions: name=VK_EXT_swapchain_colorspace, enabled=1
2019-12-22 00:09:36.055 12911-12928/{ProjectPackageName} D/Unity: [Vulkan init] extensions: name=VK_KHR_get_surface_capabilities2, enabled=0
2019-12-22 00:09:36.055 12911-12928/{ProjectPackageName} D/Unity: [Vulkan init] extensions: name=VK_EXT_debug_report, enabled=1
2019-12-22 00:09:36.055 12911-12928/{ProjectPackageName} D/Unity: [Vulkan init] extensions: name=VK_KHR_device_group_creation, enabled=0
2019-12-22 00:09:36.055 12911-12928/{ProjectPackageName} D/Unity: [Vulkan init] extensions: name=VK_KHR_external_fence_capabilities, enabled=0
2019-12-22 00:09:36.055 12911-12928/{ProjectPackageName} D/Unity: [Vulkan init] extensions: name=VK_KHR_external_memory_capabilities, enabled=0
2019-12-22 00:09:36.055 12911-12928/{ProjectPackageName} D/Unity: [Vulkan init] extensions: name=VK_KHR_get_physical_device_properties2, enabled=0
2019-12-22 00:09:36.055 12911-12928/{ProjectPackageName} D/Unity: [Vulkan init] extensions: name=VK_KHR_external_semaphore_capabilities, enabled=0
2019-12-22 00:09:36.056 12911-12928/{ProjectPackageName} I/Adreno: QUALCOMM build          : 6cbc6c9, Ib736691963
    Build Date              : 04/25/19
    Shader Compiler Version : EV031.26.03.01
    Local Branch            : 
    Remote Branch           : quic/gfx-adreno.lnx.1.0.r81-rel
    Remote Branch           : NONE
    Reconstruct Branch      : NOTHING
2019-12-22 00:09:36.056 12911-12928/{ProjectPackageName} I/Adreno: Build Config            : S P 6.0.9 AArch32
2019-12-22 00:09:36.063 12911-12928/{ProjectPackageName} I/ConfigStore: android::hardware::configstore::V1_0::ISurfaceFlingerConfigs::hasHDRDisplay retrieved: 0
2019-12-22 00:09:36.063 12911-12928/{ProjectPackageName} I/ConfigStore: android::hardware::configstore::V1_0::ISurfaceFlingerConfigs::hasHDRDisplay retrieved: 0
2019-12-22 00:09:36.063 12911-12928/{ProjectPackageName} D/Unity: [Vulkan init] extensions: count=30
2019-12-22 00:09:36.063 12911-12928/{ProjectPackageName} D/Unity: [Vulkan init] extensions: name=VK_KHR_incremental_present, enabled=0
2019-12-22 00:09:36.063 12911-12928/{ProjectPackageName} D/Unity: [Vulkan init] extensions: name=VK_KHR_shared_presentable_image, enabled=0
2019-12-22 00:09:36.063 12911-12928/{ProjectPackageName} D/Unity: [Vulkan init] extensions: name=VK_GOOGLE_display_timing, enabled=0
2019-12-22 00:09:36.063 12911-12928/{ProjectPackageName} D/Unity: [Vulkan init] extensions: name=VK_KHR_push_descriptor, enabled=0
2019-12-22 00:09:36.063 12911-12928/{ProjectPackageName} D/Unity: [Vulkan init] extensions: name=VK_KHR_image_format_list, enabled=1
2019-12-22 00:09:36.063 12911-12928/{ProjectPackageName} D/Unity: [Vulkan init] extensions: name=VK_EXT_queue_family_foreign, enabled=0
2019-12-22 00:09:36.063 12911-12928/{ProjectPackageName} D/Unity: [Vulkan init] extensions: name=VK_ANDROID_external_memory_android_hardware_buffer, enabled=0
2019-12-22 00:09:36.063 12911-12928/{ProjectPackageName} D/Unity: [Vulkan init] extensions: name=VK_KHR_external_semaphore_fd, enabled=0
2019-12-22 00:09:36.063 12911-12928/{ProjectPackageName} D/Unity: [Vulkan init] extensions: name=VK_KHR_external_fence_fd, enabled=0
2019-12-22 00:09:36.063 12911-12928/{ProjectPackageName} D/Unity: [Vulkan init] extensions: name=VK_KHR_external_memory_fd, enabled=0
2019-12-22 00:09:36.063 12911-12928/{ProjectPackageName} D/Unity: [Vulkan init] extensions: name=VK_KHR_external_memory, enabled=0
2019-12-22 00:09:36.063 12911-12928/{ProjectPackageName} D/Unity: [Vulkan init] extensions: name=VK_KHR_swapchain, enabled=1
2019-12-22 00:09:36.063 12911-12928/{ProjectPackageName} D/Unity: [Vulkan init] extensions: name=VK_KHR_external_semaphore, enabled=0
2019-12-22 00:09:36.063 12911-12928/{ProjectPackageName} D/Unity: [Vulkan init] extensions: name=VK_KHR_sampler_mirror_clamp_to_edge, enabled=1
2019-12-22 00:09:36.063 12911-12928/{ProjectPackageName} D/Unity: [Vulkan init] extensions: name=VK_KHR_multiview, enabled=0
2019-12-22 00:09:36.063 12911-12928/{ProjectPackageName} D/Unity: [Vulkan init] extensions: name=VK_KHR_relaxed_block_layout, enabled=0
2019-12-22 00:09:36.063 12911-12928/{ProjectPackageName} D/Unity: [Vulkan init] extensions: name=VK_KHR_maintenance1, enabled=1
2019-12-22 00:09:36.063 12911-12928/{ProjectPackageName} D/Unity: [Vulkan init] extensions: name=VK_KHR_maintenance3, enabled=0
2019-12-22 00:09:36.063 12911-12928/{ProjectPackageName} D/Unity: [Vulkan init] extensions: name=VK_KHR_maintenance2, enabled=0
2019-12-22 00:09:36.063 12911-12928/{ProjectPackageName} D/Unity: [Vulkan init] extensions: name=VK_KHR_get_memory_requirements2, enabled=1
2019-12-22 00:09:36.063 12911-12928/{ProjectPackageName} D/Unity: [Vulkan init] extensions: name=VK_KHR_descriptor_update_template, enabled=0
2019-12-22 00:09:36.063 12911-12928/{ProjectPackageName} D/Unity: [Vulkan init] extensions: name=VK_KHR_bind_memory2, enabled=0
2019-12-22 00:09:36.063 12911-12928/{ProjectPackageName} D/Unity: [Vulkan init] extensions: name=VK_KHR_shader_draw_parameters, enabled=0
2019-12-22 00:09:36.063 12911-12928/{ProjectPackageName} D/Unity: [Vulkan init] extensions: name=VK_KHR_dedicated_allocation, enabled=1
2019-12-22 00:09:36.063 12911-12928/{ProjectPackageName} D/Unity: [Vulkan init] extensions: name=VK_KHR_create_renderpass2, enabled=0
2019-12-22 00:09:36.063 12911-12928/{ProjectPackageName} D/Unity: [Vulkan init] extensions: name=VK_KHR_sampler_ycbcr_conversion, enabled=0
2019-12-22 00:09:36.063 12911-12928/{ProjectPackageName} D/Unity: [Vulkan init] extensions: name=VK_KHR_device_group, enabled=0
2019-12-22 00:09:36.063 12911-12928/{ProjectPackageName} D/Unity: [Vulkan init] extensions: name=VK_KHR_external_fence, enabled=0
2019-12-22 00:09:36.063 12911-12928/{ProjectPackageName} D/Unity: [Vulkan init] extensions: name=VK_KHR_variable_pointers, enabled=0
2019-12-22 00:09:36.063 12911-12928/{ProjectPackageName} D/Unity: [Vulkan init] extensions: name=VK_KHR_storage_buffer_storage_class, enabled=0
2019-12-22 00:09:36.063 12911-12928/{ProjectPackageName} I/ConfigStore: android::hardware::configstore::V1_0::ISurfaceFlingerConfigs::hasHDRDisplay retrieved: 0
2019-12-22 00:09:36.063 12911-12928/{ProjectPackageName} I/ConfigStore: android::hardware::configstore::V1_0::ISurfaceFlingerConfigs::hasHDRDisplay retrieved: 0
2019-12-22 00:09:36.069 12911-12928/{ProjectPackageName} D/Unity: Vulkan API version 1.1.87
2019-12-22 00:09:36.069 12911-12928/{ProjectPackageName} D/Unity: Vulkan vendor=[Qualcomm] id=[5143]
2019-12-22 00:09:36.069 12911-12928/{ProjectPackageName} D/Unity: Vulkan renderer=[Adreno (TM) 610] id=[6010000]
2019-12-22 00:09:36.069 12911-12928/{ProjectPackageName} D/Unity: Vulkan device type 1
2019-12-22 00:09:36.069 12911-12928/{ProjectPackageName} D/Unity: Vulkan driverversion=[512.378.0] uint=[-2145935360]
2019-12-22 00:09:36.069 12911-12928/{ProjectPackageName} D/Unity: [vulkan] ASTC HDR support: 1
2019-12-22 00:09:36.083 12911-12928/{ProjectPackageName} D/Unity: Vulkan PSO: Cache data successfully loaded [size=41206,path=/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/{ProjectPackageName}/cache/vulkan_pso_cache.bin]
2019-12-22 00:09:36.085 12911-12928/{ProjectPackageName} D/Unity: [EGL] Attaching window :0x0
2019-12-22 00:09:36.085 12911-12928/{ProjectPackageName} D/Unity: AndroidDisplayManagerVulkan::AttachWindow(0xed8c7808, 0)
2019-12-22 00:09:36.088 12911-12928/{ProjectPackageName} D/Unity: InitializeOrResetSwapChain 720x1490 samples=0
2019-12-22 00:09:36.095 12911-12928/{ProjectPackageName} I/ConfigStore: android::hardware::configstore::V1_0::ISurfaceFlingerConfigs::hasWideColorDisplay retrieved: 0
2019-12-22 00:09:36.095 12911-12928/{ProjectPackageName} I/ConfigStore: android::hardware::configstore::V1_0::ISurfaceFlingerConfigs::hasWideColorDisplay retrieved: 0
2019-12-22 00:09:36.101 12911-12928/{ProjectPackageName} D/Unity: AndroidDisplayManagerVulkan::AttachWindow(0xed8c7808, 0)
2019-12-22 00:09:36.101 12911-12928/{ProjectPackageName} D/Unity: Initialize engine version: 2019.2.17f1 (8e603399ca02)
2019-12-22 00:09:36.115 12911-12928/{ProjectPackageName} W/oss.BlockPuzzl: Accessing hidden method Landroid/media/AudioSystem;->getPrimaryOutputSamplingRate()I (light greylist, JNI)
2019-12-22 00:09:36.115 12911-12928/{ProjectPackageName} W/oss.BlockPuzzl: Accessing hidden method Landroid/media/AudioSystem;->getPrimaryOutputFrameCount()I (light greylist, JNI)
2019-12-22 00:09:36.116 12911-12928/{ProjectPackageName} I/libOpenSLES: Emulating old channel mask behavior (ignoring positional mask 0x3, using default mask 0x3 based on channel count of 2)
2019-12-22 00:09:36.116 12911-12928/{ProjectPackageName} W/AudioTrack: notificationFrames=-21 clamped to the range -1 to -8
2019-12-22 00:09:36.118 12911-12928/{ProjectPackageName} I/AudioTrack: AUDIO_OUTPUT_FLAG_FAST successful; frameCount 0 -> 1536
2019-12-22 00:09:36.130 12911-12928/{ProjectPackageName} D/Unity: Begin MonoManager ReloadAssembly
2019-12-22 00:09:36.132 12911-12928/{ProjectPackageName} D/Unity: Script Patching: Patch files are not available, '/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/{ProjectPackageName}/cache/ScriptOnly/2019.2.17f1/mono/patch.config' is missing.
2019-12-22 00:09:36.033 12911-12928/{ProjectPackageName} I/chatty: uid=10172({ProjectPackageName}) UnityMain identical 14 lines
2019-12-22 00:09:36.033 12911-12928/{ProjectPackageName} E/SchedPolicy: set_timerslack_ns write failed: Operation not permitted
2019-12-22 00:09:36.473 12911-12928/{ProjectPackageName} D/Unity: - Completed reload, in  0.343 seconds
2019-12-22 00:09:36.542 12911-12928/{ProjectPackageName} D/Unity: PlayerInitEngineGraphics OK
2019-12-22 00:09:36.545 12911-12928/{ProjectPackageName} D/Unity: Found 36 native sensors
2019-12-22 00:09:36.553 12911-12928/{ProjectPackageName} D/Unity: Sensor :        Accelerometer ( 1) ; 0.002393 / 0.00s ; BMI160_ACCELEROMETER Accelerometer Non-wakeup / BOSCH 
2019-12-22 00:09:36.557 12911-12928/{ProjectPackageName} D/Unity: Sensor :        Accelerometer ( 1) ; 0.002393 / 0.00s ; BMI160_ACCELEROMETER Accelerometer Non-wakeup / BOSCH 
2019-12-22 00:09:36.565 12911-12928/{ProjectPackageName} D/Unity: SetWindow 0 0xed8c7808
2019-12-22 00:09:36.565 12911-12928/{ProjectPackageName} D/Unity: AndroidDisplayManagerVulkan::AttachWindow(0xed8c7808, 0)
2019-12-22 00:09:36.569 12911-12928/{ProjectPackageName} D/Unity: InitializeOrResetSwapChain 720x1490 samples=0
2019-12-22 00:09:36.578 12911-12928/{ProjectPackageName} I/ConfigStore: android::hardware::configstore::V1_0::ISurfaceFlingerConfigs::hasWideColorDisplay retrieved: 0
2019-12-22 00:09:36.579 12911-12928/{ProjectPackageName} I/ConfigStore: android::hardware::configstore::V1_0::ISurfaceFlingerConfigs::hasWideColorDisplay retrieved: 0
2019-12-22 00:09:36.592 12911-12928/{ProjectPackageName} V/MediaRouter: Adding route: RouteInfo{ name=Phone, description=null, status=null, category=RouteCategory{ name=System types=ROUTE_TYPE_LIVE_AUDIO ROUTE_TYPE_LIVE_VIDEO  groupable=false }, supportedTypes=ROUTE_TYPE_LIVE_AUDIO ROUTE_TYPE_LIVE_VIDEO , presentationDisplay=null }
2019-12-22 00:09:36.595 12911-12928/{ProjectPackageName} V/MediaRouter: Selecting route: RouteInfo{ name=Phone, description=null, status=null, category=RouteCategory{ name=System types=ROUTE_TYPE_LIVE_AUDIO ROUTE_TYPE_LIVE_VIDEO  groupable=false }, supportedTypes=ROUTE_TYPE_LIVE_AUDIO ROUTE_TYPE_LIVE_VIDEO , presentationDisplay=null }
2019-12-22 00:09:38.642 12911-12928/{ProjectPackageName} D/Unity: UnloadTime: 1.956770 ms
2019-12-22 00:09:38.646 12911-12928/{ProjectPackageName} D/Unity: UUID: 9fe98dd98881bf00 => f42ec4982c1f7f49f4cb9110cb41ba68
2019-12-22 00:09:38.910 12911-12928/{ProjectPackageName} D/Unity: Sensor :        Accelerometer ( 1) ; 0.002393 / 0.00s ; BMI160_ACCELEROMETER Accelerometer Non-wakeup / BOSCH 
2019-12-22 00:09:38.918 12911-12928/{ProjectPackageName} D/Unity: Choreographer available: Enabling VSYNC timing
2019-12-22 00:09:39.014 12911-12953/{ProjectPackageName} D/NetworkSecurityConfig: No Network Security Config specified, using platform default
2019-12-22 00:09:39.211 12911-12928/{ProjectPackageName} I/Unity: [12/22/2019 00:09:39.123] ScreenSize: h = 1490, w = 720
    UnityEngine.DebugLogHandler:Internal_Log(LogType, LogOption, String, Object)
    UnityEngine.DebugLogHandler:LogFormat(LogType, Object, String, Object[])
    UnityEngine.Logger:Log(LogType, Object)
    UnityEngine.Debug:Log(Object)
    {ProjectName}.Development.DebugUtils:Log(String) (at {ProjectPath}{ProjectName}\Assets\Scripts\{ProjectName}\Development\DebugUtils.cs:35)
    {ProjectName}.CameraBehaviour:ConfigureCanvasAndCamera() (at {ProjectPath}{ProjectName}\Assets\Scripts\{ProjectName}\CameraBehaviour.cs:72)
    {ProjectName}.CameraBehaviour:Start() (at {ProjectPath}{ProjectName}\Assets\Scripts\{ProjectName}\CameraBehaviour.cs:27)

    (Filename: D Line: 0)
2019-12-22 00:09:39.213 12911-12928/{ProjectPackageName} I/Unity: [12/22/2019 00:09:39.212] CurrentResolution: h = 1490, w = 720
    UnityEngine.DebugLogHandler:Internal_Log(LogType, LogOption, String, Object)
    UnityEngine.DebugLogHandler:LogFormat(LogType, Object, String, Object[])
    UnityEngine.Logger:Log(LogType, Object)
    UnityEngine.Debug:Log(Object)
    {ProjectName}.Development.DebugUtils:Log(String) (at {ProjectPath}{ProjectName}\Assets\Scripts\{ProjectName}\Development\DebugUtils.cs:35)
    {ProjectName}.CameraBehaviour:ConfigureCanvasAndCamera() (at {ProjectPath}{ProjectName}\Assets\Scripts\{ProjectName}\CameraBehaviour.cs:73)
    {ProjectName}.CameraBehaviour:Start() (at {ProjectPath}{ProjectName}\Assets\Scripts\{ProjectName}\CameraBehaviour.cs:27)

    (Filename: D Line: 0)
2019-12-22 00:09:39.265 12911-12928/{ProjectPackageName} I/Unity: [12/22/2019 00:09:39.263] BackgroundItemsGrid Before Prepared LeftBottom: (88.5, 410.6, 0.0)
    UnityEngine.DebugLogHandler:Internal_Log(LogType, LogOption, String, Object)
    UnityEngine.DebugLogHandler:LogFormat(LogType, Object, String, Object[])
    UnityEngine.Logger:Log(LogType, Object)
    UnityEngine.Debug:Log(Object)
    {ProjectName}.Development.DebugUtils:Log(String) (at {ProjectPath}{ProjectName}\Assets\Scripts\{ProjectName}\Development\DebugUtils.cs:35)
    {ProjectName}.Game.BackgroundItems.<Prepare>d__26:MoveNext() (at {ProjectPath}{ProjectName}\Assets\Scripts\{ProjectName}\Game\BackgroundItems\BackgroundItemsGrid.cs:252)
    UnityEngine.SetupCoroutine:InvokeMoveNext(IEnumerator, IntPtr) (at /Users/builduser/buildslave/unity/build/Runtime/Export/Scripting/Coroutines.cs:17)
    UnityEngine.MonoBehaviour:StartCoroutineManaged2(IEnumerator)
    UnityEngine.MonoBehaviour:StartCoroutine(IEnumerator) (at /Users/builduser/buildslave/unity/build/Runtime/Export/Scripting/MonoBehaviour.bindings.cs:91)
    {ProjectName}.Game.Backgro
2019-12-22 00:09:39.659 12911-12928/{ProjectPackageName} D/Unity: SetWindow 0 0xed8c7808
2019-12-22 00:09:39.659 12911-12928/{ProjectPackageName} D/Unity: AndroidDisplayManagerVulkan::AttachWindow(0xed8c7808, 0)
2019-12-22 00:09:39.663 12911-12928/{ProjectPackageName} D/Unity: InitializeOrResetSwapChain 720x1560 samples=0
2019-12-22 00:09:39.666 12911-12928/{ProjectPackageName} I/ConfigStore: android::hardware::configstore::V1_0::ISurfaceFlingerConfigs::hasWideColorDisplay retrieved: 0
2019-12-22 00:09:39.667 12911-12928/{ProjectPackageName} I/ConfigStore: android::hardware::configstore::V1_0::ISurfaceFlingerConfigs::hasWideColorDisplay retrieved: 0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this issue with a "crutch" by using "Screen.SetResolution(Screen.width, Screen.height, Screen.fullScreen);" in the beginning of the "Start()" event.

After this, all the "InitializeOrResetSwapChain" events print the same resolution.